# How to detect only the contour of just the filled zones in opencv

Tags: c#, opencv

I would like to be able to detect contours of the filled zones only,
I have an input image that is like this

[image]

And I would like to be able to detect only the contours of the filled zones.(the blue ones in this image)

Comment: apply a morphological operation. that'll erase the lines. -- for findContours, it's a good idea to have objects be white and background be black, so you should maybe invert the image... findContours requires binarized (thresholded) data anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Christoph Rackwitz indeed the way is to apply a morphological operation !